# Splitting up Total Copper into Gold Silver Copper

Tags: excel

I'm converting from Gold > Silver > Copper

Right now I can get my Gold in proper form and Copper.
How do I get rid of that "09" in my "2809" Silver so it'll be a whole number and represent the Silver Properly?

For every, 100 Silver, it'll be equals to 1 Gold.

It is a profit calculator in terms of Gold Silver Copper. But before counting the profit I made, I convert the Gold and Silver into Copper and add with the current Copper to make another variable "Total Copper". So from there, I just minus of my Selling Price - Cost Price = "My Profit"

From there,how do I sort it out back to Gold Silver Copper?

An example is:

`Total Copper`
`280950`

Now I want to convert it back to `Gold` `Silver` `Copper` accordingly.

Under the `Copper` Column I have `=MOD(SILVER,100)` - This outputs 9

Under the `Silver` Column I have `=INT((TOTALCOPPER/100))` - This outputs 2809

Under the `Gold` Column I have `=INT(SILVER/100)` - This outputs 28

So how do I remove the 2809 and make it 28 since, 09 is used in the Copper already?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there's 100 copper in 1 silver, and 100 silver in 1 gold, you'd want to see 280950 copper become 28 gold, 9 silver and 50 copper. To do this, I'd do the following:

```
A1 = 280950
A2 = Gold = INT(A1/(100*100)) = 28
A3 = Silver = INT((A1 - (A2*100*100))/100) = 9
A4 = Copper = (A1 - (A2*100*100) - A3*100) = 50
```

You could equally calculate the remainder using MOD rather than doing A1 - A2*100*100, but I thought it might be clearer to do it this way for the example.

edit: You'll note that I did **not** round the value at A4. This allows you to have e.g. 50.3 copper. If you want to round it, just throw the equation in INT() to round it down.

Comment: Awesome bro. That cleared my calculation issues :) Thanks though.